# What is the "AuthTokenType" value for Google Drive on an Android app?

Tags: android, google-data-api, google-drive-api

What should I use as the "AuthTokenType" value to request access to a user's Google Drive from an Android application?

For example, here are some AuthTokenType values for other services:
[What is "authTokenType" parameter in Google data API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773804/what-is-authtokentype-parameter-in-google-data-api)

I intend to use the provided Java Client API for interfacing with Google Drive, i.e.: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API

Answer (score 4):

ClientLogin is now officially deprecated, so you should use OAuth. The scope is listed as https://developers.google.com/drive/register on the SDK [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/register). However, apparently you need to register your app in the Chrome Web store, so it seems only Web apps are currently supported, and it is very likely that you cannot use it from an Android app (yet). Do post here if  you manage to get it working.

Comment: There is apparently a google-api-client mapping available here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API As described in this post, it can also be used with the GData API or directly using the REST protocol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330053/google-drive-docs-api-for-android