# Listing all available files in Google Drive through Google Drive SDK

Tags: android, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Previously, in desktop application, I am using Google Document List API, to list out all available files in Google Drive.

http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/file/808b03e824bf/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/Utils.java#l1188

However, Google Document List API is not supported in Android platform. In order for this to work in Android platform, I need to use Google Drive SDK.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get

I do not see Google Drive SDK provides such functionality. So, what Android developers can do, to achieve **list out all available files in Google Drive** purpose?

Comment: What makes you think that Google Document List API is not support in Android? In fact the Google Drive API is not really intended to be used for Android (see restrictions, e.g. need of installation through Chrome Web Store https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview and yes this is also needed for Android Apps)

Comment: read the bottom of the page : http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/ "Since GData Java Client Library does not support Android, Android developers should instead use the new library Google API Client Library for Java.". Google Document List API is heavily depending on GData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer by @Nivco to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330053/google-drive-docs-api-for-android).

Admittedly, not a great set of options, but probably the "HTTP REST API plus XML parser" is your best bet in the near term...

Comment: Yes. You are right. After several days of try-n-error, I decide to give up, by write my own raw HTTP request and XML parser, to achieve my files and directories listing purpose.

Comment: Wow, really? Writing your own XML parser, instead of using an existing library? (Although, I guess that if you know in detail what the XML response will look like, you avoid a lot of overhead by crafting a custom parser. Is that your rationale?)