# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to implement Google Drive in my android Applciation, and getting  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential` 
 error, so anyone who know how to solve this.

I tried still now

- Successfully import all the .jar required for Google Drive
- Import Google Play Service Lib. in my project successfully
- Tried to restart eclipse and check but same error is coming
- Got an API key and Client ID from google Drive API or Play service for Android
- Already visit some solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372391/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable)

And trying same as [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java)

Here is my Logcat-

```
    03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.example.alltaskass.GoogleDrive.onCreate(GoogleDrive.java:53)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-21 15:03:55.194: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But still I am stuck for this error,and dont know how to solve this, Please guide me

Thank you in advance

Comment: clean & built? uninstall app on device and reinstall?

Comment: please Check the API Level,


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330053/google-drive-docs-api-for-android

Comment: @Seema Thanks but I already tried this

Comment: @kirtiavaiya Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Yes, It was cause as because of library problem, you can use latest lib. hope it can help you, Let me know if its not working

Comment: @kirtiavaiya Even I am using the latest lib. Can you please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510953/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-api-services-drive-drive)

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Are you testing real device or Emulator ?

Comment: Real device...API 4.1.2

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Check for Google play service latest lib and make sure you do not import two lib, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626466/noclassdeffounderrror-with-google-drive

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the user defined JAR file ( that is you have converted JAVA file into JAR file in order to import the library for your own use ) which you have compiled in the library for this application. In order to overcome this error you have to just take the JAVA file and you have give in a separate class in your package.

Comment: I am not getting you ,will you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved this by exporting all the drive related jars (mark with "v") in "Order and Export" tab of the build window.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until a minute ago. In your app's properties make sure you are targeting an API level with Google API's. They will be listed right below the target level (4.0.3 in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by add google-play-service

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by the following:

1. check Drive API in **Project Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export**

   thereafter Drive API jars added to the project to lib folder
2. uncheсk Drive API