# NoClassDefFoundErrror with Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've got a project which had Google Drive included and it was all working perfectly fine. Then I performed an upgrade of the Android SDK and Eclipse ADT Plugin and Google Drivie no longer works and I can't understand why.

I've added the Drive API to my project as well as Google Play Services and tick on the checkbox to export. I've done a clean build, I've deleted the bin directory of my app, restarted eclipse, re-did the clean build but as soon as I run the section of my app which should show the google account chooser the app crashes.

Below is the error returned in the logcat

```
05-18 17:17:09.089: E/AndroidRuntime(16747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 17:17:09.089: E/AndroidRuntime(16747): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker
05-18 17:17:09.089: E/AndroidRuntime(16747):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(GoogleAccountCredential.java:171)
```

No matter what I try it doesn't seem to make any difference.

### Update

I've tried ticking the export option for Android Private Libraries as Raghunandan suggested. Most of the app is working such as the Dropbox API that is also included in the project but I still get the error when the Google Drive part of the code is executed, with the NoClassDefFoundError.

If I tick the Drive API within the Order & Export Tab I then get an error `Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/accounts/GoogleAccountManag‌​er;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are importing multiple libraries defining class `com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.accounts.GoogleAccountManag‌er`. Look into Package Manager, under Android Private Libraries and try opening .jar files there. You will probably find this class in at least two of them (one of them might be something like `google-api-client-android-1.13.2-beta.jar`).

Try excluding one of the jar files from your build path. If you have no errors, you are done. If there are errors, try excluding the other jar file. If errors remain, you can try opening jar as zip and manually deleting the `GoogleAccountManager.class` file.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Its been bugging me for ages. There was another step that I didn't do though. I included the google play services in the build path and exported but didn't add it as a library in the android section of the project. Thanks for your help. Its been bugging me for days

Comment: @ferini I had the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510953/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-api-services-drive-drive). And like you said the **Drive class is present in 2 jars**. one in the `googl-play-services.jar` and the other in `google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar` But why does this happen even after giving the right import path?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Project -> Properties -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using.

Comment: Thanks I've tried this but I now get the following error ``Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/accounts/GoogleAccountManager;
[2013-05-18 21:29:11 - AndroidPasswordManager] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/accounts/GoogleAccountManager;``

Comment: Have you referred to the google play services library?.Also try this 
After updating Android SDK and ADT make sure you have Android Build tools installed.

Goto your android sdk manager check if Andorid Build Tools is installed. If not installed install the same.

Comment: Yea google Play services is referenced in the project. I've checked the SDK manager everything is up to date and the Android SDK Build Tools is installed

Comment: @Boardy have you imported this import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;

Comment: It is yea. This code was all working fine and the current code is active on the play store. I'm just trying to do a new release but for some reason the SDK upgrade has broken the app.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and solved it now.

First I try to download the [Dredit](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit), and it works fine!! So I remove the google api from properties (properties->Java Build Path->Libraries). and copy the libs from Dredit. Guess what? the problem still exist.

So I do the following steps to rebuild whole project, and this problem has solved. Hope it can help you.

1. Remove googe api and all related libs.
2. Close this project
3. Open the project folder and remove and hidden folder (start with .) and generated folder
4. Re-include project again. And Copy the libs form Dredit