# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.services.drive.Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

While trying to use any Drive class function:

```
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

I have included the right jar in the libs folders:

> google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar

and the imports are fine:

> import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive; import
>   com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

But it keeps on showing the error:

```
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Builder
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at com.example.googledrivetest.MainActivity$getAccountDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:138)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at com.example.googledrivetest.MainActivity$getAccountDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-07 11:54:37.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25824):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: right click add to build path..and clean the project

Comment: Nope. The same error.

Comment: I'm wondering, there's no file named 'google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar' in the featured zip file in google-api-java-client page,

Comment: @EBLiS It is from here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2

Comment: After placing the jar in lib folder, did you add the jar to the android project by configuring the build path? If not then try this : right click the project -> Build path -> Configure build path -> Libraries tab -> Add Jars -> select and add google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar from libs folder.

Comment: @ManishMulimani Yeah I did that. Still the same problem.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc There were a few set of jars that need to be included to solve the problem. I have posted the answer.

Comment: I solved my problem too,now I have a nice GD client to upload/download/explore ,Let me know if you needed any help @Archie.bpgc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have not included `google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar` library, that is the reason you are getting the exception.

Once you download and unzip the [Drive API library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/drive/v2/java), please read the `drive/readme.html`. It has listed the dependent jars for `google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar` that need to be included. The dependent jars can be located in `drive/libs` folder.

Following are the complete set of jars that need to be included for Android application:

- google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar
- google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
- google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
- google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
- jsr305-1.3.9.jar
- google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar
- google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
- google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar