# Google Translation Api in Android

Tags: android, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using Google Translation api in android and I'm having the following error: `GoogleAPI class def is not found`. If anyone has a solution, please reply fast.

```
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.GoogleAPI
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.example.translate.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-18 21:55:59.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 21:56:02.724: I/Process(1449): Sending signal. PID: 1449 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544080/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-andr)

Trying with it,

If not help, **please define CLASS environment for this *.jar** (GoogleTranslateAPI.jar).

And build again,

It should be fine.