# Writing to Google Drive from an Android app

Tags: android, maven, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm working on an Android app where I need to write to a Google Drive spreadsheet.  There's a quick start video on "Google Developers Live" that seems to go through most of the required steps, but for the library usage they just say to click some button in Eclipse.  I'm not using Eclipse though and would like to make this work with a maven project.

What libraries are required and how can I get them all using maven?

Here's the part of the video I'm talking about: http://youtu.be/Ied1CjJ0iP0?t=9m41s

Also, I've found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330497/605331) and the latest edit says to use the Drive API V2 but a google api client is linked.  I'm not exactly sure what's needed or if perhaps something has changed since then.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Google API Java Client. Downloads for Drive are here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API

Comment: One thing to add to this... I was able to get it mostly working although I also had to use the exclusions listed here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-api-java-client/hGOFocur-vQ/Ahfx2cJdF9AJ
Otherwise some dependencies are brought in that cause issues when compiling.

Comment: This has gotten me a bit further, but now I seem to be missing some other libraries.  From the example the GoogleAccountCredential, GoogleAccountCredential, and UserRecoverableAuthIOException classes are missing.  What do I need to use to get these?