# How to store xauth token in android

Tags: android, android-security

I'm developing an android app in which user is authenticated using **XAuth** token.I don't want to store this token in SharedPreference or SQLite.because it stores data as a plain text.How to store token in android device.

Comment: Use the AccountManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: Is it possible to get/steal token which is stored using account manager from rooted devices?

Comment: It's a complex issue.. It depend of the types of sensitive resources. Try to reed this thread for more informations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437096/shouldnt-android-accountmanager-store-oauth-tokens-on-a-per-app-uid-basis

Answer (score 0):

Use secure SharedPreferences. It's not bullet proof, but vastly increases the security.

Find an explanation here: https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences